# Write back buffer in lpc

Tags: arm

I was reading the **Lpc2148 Manual** and in the Static Ram section I came across

> **Write back buffer**

The **SRAM** controller incorporates a **write-back buffer** in order to prevent CPU stalls
during back-to-back writes. The write-back buffer always holds the last data sent by
software to the SRAM. This data is only written to the SRAM when another write is
requested by software.(the data is only written to the SRAM when software does another
write). If a chip reset occurs, actual SRAM contents will not reflect the most recent write
request (i.e. after a "warm" chip reset, the SRAM does not reflect the last write operation).
Any software that checks SRAM contents after reset must take this into account. Two
identical writes to a location guarantee that the data will be present after a Reset.

What does it mean. and what did he mean by **CPU stalls** and **back to back writes**

Comment: Question might have been better at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg Thanks Bro i was not aware about this site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an EE so this is a layman's analogy. You are the only shopper at a supermarket. Because business is slow, there is only one cashier working this shift. There is no checkout counter - only a cashier and a barcode scanner. You hand items, one at a time, to the cashier. When the cashier is holding an item, they cannot take another item. Only when the cashier is done scanning an item, can they accept another one. If you don't have a bag or a cart and you bring individual items from the shelves to the cashier, there is no problem. But if you bring more than one item to the cashier and try to hand them all at once (back to back) you can't. You hand them one by one and you wait for each to be processed. This is called a stall.

Suddenly, the checkout counter with the conveyor belt is invented. Now you place your shopping at the counter and are free to go shop for more stuff. The cashier scans items at their own (slow) pace, because there is both a place for you to put them and a way for the cashier to reach them. The number of items you can put on the counter is limited, but it does allow you to drop off some stuff and continue shopping, making your shopping much more efficient.

There is a slight problem: before the invention of the checkout counter, when you wanted to know how much money the shopping spree is going to cost you, you could just look at the total displayed by the cash register. But now, you need to look at the cash register *and* the items on the counter that have not yet been processed.

That's why the read-from-SRAM instruction first surreptitiously checks whether the address you're reading from is one of the addresses to-be-written-to in the write queue/buffer. If so, it takes the value from the latest write-queue-entry with the same address instead of actually reading from SRAM. Reads from addresses that are in the write queue can be faster than reads from SRAM, but reads from addresses that are not currently in the write queue are made a little slower by the overhead (or at least less energy efficient, if SRAM reads and cache searches are done in parallel). Overall, this makes reads worse but the gains from no waiting for writes are worth it.

What they are telling you is that their cashier has an off-by-one bug: it drains the write queue not until it is empty but until there is only one item left on the counter. A snickers bar. And then, the cashier will look at that snickers bar forever and not put it through checkout. If you need to purchase the snickers bar, you need to put another item on the counter. Then, the cashier will happily move the conveyor belt and take the snickers bar. The text suggests you use another snickers bar, but you don't have to. In general, the last item you put on the counter will never be processed by the cashier.